# White Border Brush On AppBarButton - Windows Phone 8.1 (Runtime / Universal App)

Tags: windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

this is only happening in Windows Phone 8.1 Preview for Developers, so I think it's a bug. I'm looking for some workaround.

The **AppBarButtons** are with a **white border brush** while focusing, take a look in the bottom of the image:

[image]

I noticed this only happens when I override **CommandBarForegroundThemeBrush**, in my case to Black, and the phone theme is Black. When the phone theme is White, the border is black.

If someone know any workaround please tell me. Or the right place to submit this issue to the wp team.

I tried changing a lot of resources, including  FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush and FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush, but it has no effect.

Thanks.

Comment: My workaround by now: I set RequestTheme="Dark" on CommandBar, so the foreground will be white and I'll not notice the border. But not satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue with a couple apps and just request it for the whole application on start in the App.xaml.cs constructor.

```
public App()
{
  this.RequestedTheme = ApplicationTheme.Dark;
  this.InitializeComponent();
  this.Suspending += this.OnSuspending;            
}
```

Comment: Hi, I just did it to test. But my app set the CommandBarForegroundThemeBrush to Black, and when I do it the problem happens anyway. One workaround is to stop changing this resource, then the foreground will be white and I won't notice the white border, and this is what your solution is doing indirectly, but I would like it to be black